# Cannot write WhatsApp message directly from address book

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, android-12

I used to be able to see a contact in the address book (Contacts), and have an icon to jump straight to writing a message in WhatsApp.
Also, whenever I added a phone number for a contact, if that phone number was ok for receiving WhatsApp messages, the icon showed up after a few seconds. So this was also a quick way to check if a phone number that I added was good for receiving WhatsApp messages.

Now I don't see that anymore. Is there a way to recover that?

Using Android 12 in a Galaxy S10e.

Comment: it might be some integration issue. clear data/cache for both apps if you have backup on cloud for both apps. you can also try reinstalling the apps.

Comment: @MANI - Do you have android 12? Do you see that integration?

Comment: Yes, I have used all Android versions. Never faced this kind of issue. I'm using Google Phone app as of now. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @MANI - So far, I have cleared cache in both apps, and checked they have the required permissions. This didn't help. The two next steps 1) Clearing data, 2) Reinstalling apps, require more preparation, with a backup.
Many of my contacts are stored in the phone, so they are not backed up to my Google account (and I would rather keep it that way).